# Magento multiple address checkout overview

Tags: checkout

Actually just want to ask a question about the red highlight part below:

[image]

I found that data on

```
/app/design/frontend/default/myskin/template/checkout/multishipping/overview.phtml
<tfoot>
<?php echo $this->renderTotals($this->getShippingAddressTotals($_address)); ?>
</tfoot>
```

Is it possible to get each data from that variable? I mean I want to style it in a separate column, not just inside one table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Totals are rendered one by one. Have a look at the folder `app/design/frontend/default/yourskin/template/tax/checkout`, maybe you could apply your styles there.